# Число пользователей и сделанных ими записей за дату

Tags: sql

Добрый вечер.

Как написать sql запрос, возвращающий число пользователей и число записей, произведенных ими за определенную дату в 7.01.2012. Дата хранится в формате `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.

Заранее благодарен.

**Дополнено из комментария**.

```
CREATE TABLE GK(
  state_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  state_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

  PRIMARY KEY (download_id)
);
```

Comment: фигасе, в начале неплохо бы добавить "Приказываю, царским указом"...

Comment: Покажите структуру таблицы с которой делаете выборку.

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok, ни к чему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) 
FROM gk 
WHERE date_format(state_time ,'%d.%m.%Y')='7.01.2012' 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: спасибо огромное очень благодарен

Comment: Лучше так:

    WHERE state_time BETWEEN '7.01.2012' AND '7.01.2012 23:59:59'

С типом `TIMESTAMP` можно работать также как и с `DATETIME`. Если разработчик поставит индекс на поле `state_time`, то такое условие будет делать выборку с учетом индекса.

И, вообще, желательно избегать функций в левом операнде при сравнении.

Comment: Спасибо огромное